# Is there a word/term for a (software) build in Spanish?

Tags: traducción, informática

In computing, a [build](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_build) is a compiled piece of software; that is, the actual product or result of the compilation process. I've found sources on the web which use "*compilación*", but I feel this describes rather the process and not the end product, which is what the English term designates. Is there a better word for this in Spanish, which more closely describes the English term?

Comment: As a programer, I use _archivo compilado_, m., ("compiled file"), and _ejecutable_, m., ("executable"). If referring to a numbered build, an alternative is _versión_, f. ("version").

Comment: I'm much the same as Rafael. But if I say something like "in/for the new build, I've added...", I'll use *compilación*. It just depends a lot on context

Comment: Almost as @Rafael said but  I'd use **"compilación"** if it is a build for testing or anything different from a release. I'd use **"versión"** when it is the build to be released. If you are talking to another IT savvy person you could use just "build" :-)

Comment: Tal vez sea más cercano al concepto en inglés usar "compilado"; indicando el producto de la compilación e inferiendo distintas fuentes que requieren compilación.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that the DLE is updated with the modern meaning of *compilar*:

> **[compilar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=A11NS9d)**
>
> Del lat. *compilāre* 'plagiar'.
>
> 1. tr. Allegar o reunir en un solo cuerpo de obra, partes, extractos o materias de otros varios libros o documentos.
> 2. tr. Inform. Convertir un programa en lenguaje máquina a partir de otro programa de computadora escrito en otro lenguaje.

The second meaning is the new one, but the verb also has an old meaning, that also appears in the derivated word:

> **[compilación](http://dle.rae.es/?id=A0xFJKG)**
>
> Del lat. *compilatio*, -ōnis 'saqueo', 'plagio'.
>
> 1. f. Acción y efecto de compilar.
> 2. f. Obra que reúne informaciones, preceptos o doctrinas aparecidas antes por separado o en otras obras.

Taking the first meaning, it seems that as you say, a *compilación* is the process of *building the build*. But the second meaning refers to an already compilated work. So taking this second meaning, we can infer that a *compilación* is also the produced *build*, by the similarities in the concepts of *build* and *compilation*.

If you seek other alternatives, maybe ***[ensamblado](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Fc6AACO)*** (from *ensamblar*: "preparar un programa en lenguaje máquina a partir de un programa en lenguaje simbólico"), ***construcción***, ***compilado*** or just ***build*** could work.

Comment: I would recommend using "**compilado**" rather than _compilación_ in order to refer to the product of the compilation.

Answer (score 1):

The term you´re looking for is "programa". It´s used to define the compiled build, but it can also be used to define the source code.

If you´re in a technical context, you can use "compilación", but it really is the process of compiling. In spanish you can use the present participle as a name. But outside the technical context the word used is "programa"

Comment: Nótese que `bulid` se utiliza también para hablar de webs ([esta misma](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/285175/209901)). Éstas no son programas, sino aplicaciones.

Comment: A todo esto, ¡bienvenido a [spanish.se]!

Comment: See my comment in @CptEric's answer. The linked Wikipedia article specifically chooses "artifacts" as opposed to program or executable precisely because of the distinction. Welcome from me as well! :)

Comment: @fedorqui don't welcome him so much....It is an unregistered user.  I still think that you should be registred to answer  hahaha

Comment: @DGaleano yeah... "Solo el eco me responde" hahaha. I just found this relevant post about it [“Post as guest” is a bad user experience and encourages low quality contributions. Get rid of it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/243712/209901). Probably worth adding to [your question](http://meta.spanish.stackexchange.com/q/2473/1674) in Meta.

Answer (score 1):

The world you're looking for is "Ejecutable".

> En informática, un ejecutable o archivo ejecutable, es tradicionalmente un archivo binario, o como se le conoce habitualmente, cuyo contenido se interpreta por el ordenador como un programa.

[Ejecutable, Wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ejecutable)

Comment: The output of a build isn't always/necessarily an executable, though. In continous integration scenarios, for example, one can be concerned only with the fact that the build and subsequent tests succeed. *Ejecutable* doesn't quite work here, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

*Build* es una **construcción** o **prototipo**. Se refiere a una versión operativa de un producto software que incorpora un subconjunto de las funciones que se incluirán en el producto final. Generalmente se identifica por un número de compilación, en lugar de por un número de versión.

Comment: While it is true that builds _can_ be prototypes, not all builds are prototypes necessarily (e.g. release builds).

Comment: This is true, hence the distinction between 'prototipo', Wikipedia dixit for [prototype](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prototype): "A prototype is an early sample, model, or release of a product built to test a concept ..." and 'construcción'  as release build or [release engineering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Release_engineering).

Comment: Pues a mí me gusta la respuesta. +1, a ver si te vemos en breve con más respuestas :)